# How to scale font, code behind on ipad in xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, appdelegate

Example:
created design in xaml. which looks perfect in iphone. same design fonts are small on ipad because of resolution. how can we make it bigger changing in one place.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Use Styles. When app starts up, switch in a different ResourceDictionary, based on the device metrics. See [Styling for Multiple Device Resolutions](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/styling-for-multiple-device-resolutions/).